# BackgroundAgent ReaderWriterLockSlim synchronization

Tags: multithreading, background, windows-phone, synchronization

I'm trying to synchronize access to IsolatedStorage between foreground and BackgroundAgent. The problem is that when I enter the lock I Have one thread, but after awaiting in storage access, the thread is the other one and I get SynchronizationLockException. Does anybody know the way to solve the problem. Why are the threads different in the first place? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use thread-affine locks with `async` code. With `async` code on background threads, any thread pool thread may resume the `async` method. It's not any better with UI threads either; after an `await`, you will resume on the UI thread, but *any arbitrary code runs in the meantime*, which completely defeats the *purpose* of a lock.

I recommend you use `SemaphoreSlim` instead.

Comment: So just to understand better. In general, I should avoid using ReaderWriterLockSlim, Mutex in situations, when I need synchronize on awaitable functions, am I right?

Comment: That is correct. `SemaphoreSlim` is an adequate `async`-compatible replacement for both of those.

Comment: He can't use SemaphoreSlim because background agents live in the separate process, and SemaphoreSlim can only synchronize threads in a single process.

Answer (score 0):

Background agents work in a separate process.

You can't use SemaphoreSlim because you need a named synchronization primitive to synchronize two processes. When I did what you’re doing, I used a named `Mutex` instance + blocking file IO API that happens in a single thread, but I only needed to write a few kilobytes max.

If you need to concurrently write large files, you can write them asynchronously into a temp file, then wait for the mutex, rename the temp file to the destination file name, then release the mutex.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the problem was also the same with Mutex: the awaitable function returned in different Thread and Mutex couldn't have been released. The post above explained the problem and solution